# Visual Studio 2015 - "0 authors"

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In VS2015 the line above each method or class definition, there's:

`n references | m authors | q changes`

where `n,m,q` are presumably independent unsigned integers

How do I get the author count to update from "0 authors" to 1?

Answer (score 1):

The information line on top of each method is a feature called Code Lens, introduced in Visual Studio 2013. You see authors and number of changes when you are working on a solution that has configured a Team Foundation Server or Git repository.

The authors tag lists every author that made changes each method and to the class. To rise the changes counter, modify the method and commit changes.

Open the Team Explorer tab on the SolutionExplorer to make a commit.
https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC673340.png

After commiting you should see yourself as an author.

Comment: I have an issue where the function has been in source control for a while, but still lists as "0 authors, 0 changes" (for example). Other functions are displaying data (albeit slightly incorrect at times). Using non-TFS Git.